Part of my Mesh separates from the rest when I run the animation
I finally got the cloth physics to work how I want but now the laces at the front separate from the main mesh when I run the animation.



Your lace needs to be linked to the cloth with some edges, otherwise it will detach apart

@moonboots would you like me to reopen and answer?

Yes it would be intrresting  ;)  @Harry McKenzie

Your lace needs to be linked to the cloth with some edges, otherwise it will come off:

Once animated:

Even edges that link the meshes are enough, and they will be invisible in render:

